# Odoo multi companies - model missing company_id field

Tags: odoo

I am implementing a multi-company project and noticed that several models in the payroll modules are missing the company_id field.

Is there any official documentation explaining what would be the behavior of Odoo's multi-company environment
when company_id is not defined in a model?

I made some tests...

When I created records from these models, I noticed two different behavior.
On one occasion the record was shared between companies (as if there were a company_id field set to false).

On another case, the record is not visible outside the company from where I created it.

Thanks

Comment: Which version? Also is it enterprise or community edition?

Comment: Thanks It is odoo 15 entreprise